# Unable to download a Spacy model in Rasa

Tags: python, python-3.x, spacy, rasa

I'm trying to initialize a Rasa project following these steps:

```
$ python3 -m venv --system-site-packages ./venv
$ source ./venv/bin/activate
$ pip3 install rasa[spacy]~=1.9.3
$ rasa --version
Rasa 1.9.3
```

Everything seems to be installed correctly.

Now I tried to load a Spacy model and got this error:

```
$ python3 -m spacy download en_core_web_md
(...)/venv/bin/python3: No module named spacy
```

Thanks for your help!
Thierry

Comment: I'm not an expert in Python or pip, but I installed Spacy this way: `pip install -U spacy`

Comment: Thanks very much for your comment! The problem was related to my python installation: `python3` refers to version 3.5 whereas `pip3` refers to version 3.6...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the python3 command refers to python 3.5 and pip3 command to python 3.6. Using python3.6 instead fixes the problem.

Thierry